# Cannot pass null to stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I am trying to execute a stored proc defined as such:

```
PROCEDURE [dbo].[SearchEmployees]
    @employeeId INT = NULL,
    @userName VARCHAR(50) = NULL,
    @firstName VARCHAR(50) = NULL,
    @lastName VARCHAR(50) = NULL

...
SELECT *
FROM Employee e
WHERE e.EmployeeId = @employeeId
    OR e.UserName LIKE(@userName)
    OR e.FirstName LIKE(@firstName)
    OR e.LastName LIKE(@lastName)
```

And I am calling it from code like this:

```
//employeeId = null, userName = "b.evans", firstName = "Bob", lastName = "Evans"
...
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@employeeId", employeeId);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userName", userName);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@firstName", firstName);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lastName", lastName);
try
{
    connection.Open();
    using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            results.Add(mapper.Map(reader));
        }
    }
}
finally
{
    connection.Close();
}
```

But I am getting this error:

> The parameterized query '(@employeeId nvarchar(4000),@userName nvarchar(7),@firstName nva' expects the parameter '@employeeId', which was not supplied.

Why does the database care if the employee Id is null?

EDIT:

I forgot to mention a very important detail: even if `@employeeId` is populated, in this case, let's say with the value `54`, it will throw the same complaint, yet it will execute just fine through a SQL prompt.

Comment: try to convert `employeeId` to `int`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can pass a null, but it must be a DBNull.

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@employeeId", employeeId ?? DBNull.Value);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm actually not sure, but I faintly recall it should be DBNull.Value.

Comment: Or don't pass anything in case of NULL at all and let the default take over

Comment: I realized I had forgotten to post the rest of the question, I will investigate this strategy and get back to you on it though.

Comment: Okay I modified the code to pass in a DBNull.Value in the event that the id is null and it got me past the error.  Thanks!

Comment: @jokulmorder: if you feel this answer helped you solve your problem, then please [**accept this answer**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5234/153998). This will show your appreciation for the people who *spent their own time to help you*.

Comment: sorry, the timer limit prevented me from doing so.